# Discrete math: How many arrangements are there of the 26 letters of the alphabet in which the five vowels are in consecutive places?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Getting homework done and either my mind isn't clear or I'm just overthinking this.

To get all arrangements of the 26 letters in the alphabet, it would be done by $26!$ , correct?

Okay, so I'm thinking that the five vowels (A,E,I,O,U) can be treated as one space. This means that I could find all arrangements with vowels in consecutive order by doing $22!$ .

Thinking of it as 22 blank spaces, the 22nd space is a single space made up of all five vowels while the other 21 spaces can be any other letter without repetition.

Furthermore, if I want to also include all arrangements of of the vowels as well, would this be done by $22! \cdot 5!$ ?

Thank you

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

We can consider that the five vowels are just one letter , so we have now 22 letters wanted to be arranged ,the number of arrangements is $$22!$$
but the number of permutations of the vowels them selves is $$5!$$
So the total ways of arrangement is $$22! \times 5!$$